# NextJs use images in public folder in markdown post

Tags: next.js

I'm using `gray-matter` to write markdown posts in nextjs, but having trouble accessing images to use in the blog posts.

this is my `getStaticProps`

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const fileName = fs.readFileSync(`posts/${params.slug}.md`, 'utf-8')
  const { data: frontmatter, content } = matter(fileName)
  return {
    props: {
      frontmatter,
      content,
    },
  }
}
```

in my public folder I have:

```
public
 - images
  - triangle.jpg
```

and my blog post looks like this:

```
---
# title: 'Home'
metaTitle: 'blah'
metaDesc: 'blah- blah'
date: '2022-09-30'
---

### Blah Blah

blah-de-blah, blah blah blah

![triangle](/public/images/triangle.jpg)
```

I've read the documentation on nextjs about accessing static files, but how do I access them using markdown?

Answer (score 6):

ah ok.

you omit the public folder in the source reference:

`![rightangle](/images/right-angle-triangle.jpeg)` instead.

Comment: So in other words, you omit the public folder? Could you please edit the answer and make it clearer to future readers? Thanks.

Comment: This solves the problem but with minor issue in markup preview. I don't mind in the preview as long as it works in my site